# Doctrine 2, OneToMany never populated

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, one-to-many, symfony

I'm having hard time with OneToMany relation, Doctrine never populate the Collection.

Here is my classes:

```
class User
{
    ...
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Post", mappedBy="idUser", cascade={"all"})
     */
    private $posts;

    public function getPosts() {
       return $this->posts;
    }

    public function __construct() {
        $this->posts = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }
    ...
}


class Post {
    ...
    /**
     * @var \AppBundle\Entity\User
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\User" , inversedBy="posts" , cascade={"all"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_user", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $idUser;
    ...
}
```

When I get a User object like so :

```
$user = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('AppBundle:User')->find(1);
```

`$user` is populated but `$posts` is `null`

Also if I do `$user->getPosts()` it return `null`

Why `$posts` is null ? it should be at least an `array`

My DB has a Post linked to the User 1

If I do the same with `Post`, the post is auto populated with the associate User

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

In your Post class do you have:

```
public function setUser($user){
    $user->addPost($this);
    $this->user= $user;
}
```

Probably you need something like that.

Edit 2 after this.

Also in User class, it should be like this:

```
private $posts = null;
...
/*
 * Add posts to the array.
 */
public function addPost($post){
    $this->stu_posts [] = $post;
}
```

Comment: I added it, but still `posts` is null

Comment: I updated my post. Probably you don't have it setup correctly - check it like I've indicated. This should work.

Comment: Let me know if you still have problems.

Comment: Still have the issue. I think it something to do with circular dependencies and prevent them